# Mockable clock meeting std::chrono TrivialClock requirement and interface

Tags: c++, c++11, mocks

I'm using the time for e.g. ping and timeout calculation as well as animations in a game. So my (big) codebase uses `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` in many places. For testing I'd like to test those without having to resort to `sleep` and friends (timeout of >=5mins will be hard to test this way...)

For this I created a custom `Clock` class that uses a singleton-like instance which can be changed to provide a custom clock. A default of `steady_clock` is used for production code. This `Clock` can be used as a drop-in replacement of  `std::chrono::steady_clock` and can be mocked in test code.

I'd like a review with suggestions how to improve this or if it has any flaws. Pointers to similar/better implementations are also welcome. I'm mostly concerned about the multiple indirections (and related performance penalties) this causes: Lookup of a "constructed" flag, the impl and the vtable (3 pointers) although I only have 1 function. See [godbold](https://godbolt.org/z/Sid-Z8)

```
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

struct BaseClock
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using time_point = Clock::time_point;
    virtual ~BaseClock() = default;
    virtual time_point now(){ return std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
};

class Clock
{
    static std::unique_ptr<BaseClock>& inst(){
        static std::unique_ptr<BaseClock> clock(new BaseClock);
        return clock;
    }
public:
    using rep = BaseClock::Clock::rep;
    using duration = BaseClock::Clock::duration;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;

    static time_point now(){ return time_point(inst()->now().time_since_epoch()); }
    static void set(std::unique_ptr<BaseClock> clock){inst() = std::move(clock);}
};

int main()
{
    return Clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
}
```

Example usage in test code:

```
struct MockClock: public BaseClock{
    static time_point current;
    time_point now() override { return current; }
};

void test_method(){
    Clock::set(new MockClock);
    MockClock::current = MockClock::time_point(100);
    testClass.methodUsingClock();
    MockClock::current += std::chrono::seconds(10);
    REQUIRE(testClass.checkTimeout());
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `BaseClock` ?

What's advantage against using directly `std::chrono` ? 

Avoid naked `new`, use `std::make_unique` instead.

Comment: @Calak: IIUC the point of `BaseClock` is to provide a baseline clock interface without direct dependencies. A user expecting a `const BaseClock&` or similiar can now write code independent of the underlying clock type. This allows for switching the underlying clock on a higher level without affecting the dependent code (kind of "dependency injection for clocks"). As a side effect, this allows for easier test setups (especially for weird corner cases). // I'm not a fan of the singleton in `Clock`, though.

Comment: @Calak In test code you need to mock the time, that's the whole purpose that I stated in the intro. Hence you need some injection point which the virtual `BaseClock::now()` provides while defaulting to `std::chrono`. I added a usage example to make this clearer.

Comment: @hoffmale You are correct, although the code does not get `BaseClock&` but simply uses `Clock` as a drop-in replacement for `std::chrono::*clock` (I edited the question to highlight this) So yes this is exactly dependency injection but without passing it as (template or regular) parameters which would require massive changes to the codebase. As clocks are static classes a singleton is required, I don't see a way avoiding this.

Answer (score 6):

While I think the underlying idea is quite nice, the actual implementation and design has some issues.

## Wrong Abstraction Level

Let's start with the less obvious one: How would you actually use `Clock` or `BaseClock` with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` or `std::chrono::system_clock`?

The simplest approach would be something akin to this:

```
struct HighResClock : BaseClock {
    time_point now() override { return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); }
};
```

It seems so clean, so simple, and so easy. Except that it doesn't compile! That's because `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` is not the same as `BaseClock::time_point` (and cannot easily be converted, if at all possible).

But: Do we actually need `time_point`s in the public interface?

The only reason to expose `time_point` values is to extract time differences between them. But that only matters if arbitrary `time_point`s are to be compared.

> Technically, the `time_point` could be stored in some form. However, for many clocks, like `std::chrono::steady_clock` or `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`, the epoch from when the clock are measuring their time offset can change between different executions of the same program (e.g. because the computer got rebooted).
>
> This makes storing `time_point`s, especially those not obtained from `std::chrono::system_clock`, rather useless. In that case, you'll likely need a calendar library (or similar) to get points of time in a storable format.

But in most cases, a simple `Timer` abstraction can fulfill all clock needs (comparing some `time_point`s with some relation). A simple `Timer` interface could look like this:

```
struct timer {
    // choose an appropriate duration type
    using duration = std::chrono::duration<double>;

    virtual ~timer() = default;
    
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual duration stop() = 0;
    virtual duration tick() = 0; // to obtain multiple measurements from the same baseline
};

class steady_timer : public timer {
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using time_point = clock::time_point;

    time_point start_time;
    bool running;

public:
    steady_timer() = default;

    void start() override
    {
        start_time = clock::now();
        running = true;
    }

    duration tick() override
    {
        return duration(clock::now() - start_time);
    }

    duration stop() override
    {
        auto elapsed = tick();
        running = false;
        return elapsed;
    }
};
```

Now the only exposed part of the interface is the duration. And it is easily extensible to other time sources (e.g. Win32 `QueryPerformanceCounter`) or mockable.

## Singleton

I really don't like the `Clock` singleton. Yes, it is easy to just ask a global clock. Yes, it is also easy to screw all code depending on this clock by changing the underlying instance.

For example, a test setting `Clock` to a mock but not restoring the original clock breaks all other tests that assume the default clock implementation - making test failure dependent on test execution order.

Instead, take a reference or pointer to a `timer` as parameter. This allows you to pass in a clock where needed, without changing (or corrupting) everyone elses `timer`.

Rewriting your test case:

```
class mock_timer : public timer {
    std::vector<duration> measurements;
    int counter = 0;

public:
    mock_timer(std::initializer_list<duration> il) : measurements(il) {}

    void start() override {}

    duration tick() override
    {
        if(counter < measurements.size()) return measurements[counter++];
        return measurements.back();
    }

    duration stop() override
    {
        return measurements.back(); // just example
    }
};

void test_method(){
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    mock_timer my_timer{ 10s };

    testClass.methodUsingClock(my_timer);
    
    // or, more likely:
    testclass inst{my_timer};
    inst.methodUsingClock();

    REQUIRE(testClass.checkTimeout());
}
```

Comment: I understand your arguments But I see problems with that: Time is something global, so it makes sense for it being a singleton/global. Passing it to every class would require huge refactoring and passing things down in aggregates etc. which shows another problem: Your timer class cannot be reused! So e.g. a class that needs 2 timers cannot reuse the timer as it would restart. BUT: What if I use my design but change `BaseClass::now` to return a duration? Then the underlying clock does not matter as long is it returns "time since epoch" and is not changed while a Clock::time_point is held.

Comment: @Flamefire: I'm not sure if I am getting your whole argument. I don't think time is something global. Instead, everything has its own perspective on time. For example, a game might be using one clock for rendering and a different clock for logic updates. Why? Because if gameplay is paused (e.g. when entering a menu), the graphics should still continue to be rendered because otherwise the screen would freeze. // RE "time since epoch": When is epoch? What if the epoch changes because the clock is changed? Having mutable global state is just waiting for accidents to happen.

Comment: Even your timer needs a clock. And all instances of that (at least in the same logical unit) need to use the same clock. Otherwise the relative time won't match (or at least it is not ensured) For your example: Yes if paused the *timer* needs to be paused too, but the *time* does not. So you need different timers, but I don't see the need for different clocks. // "mutable global state": I actually don't want nor need it to be mutable. It should be set once: Start of program or start of test. Then the epoch stays the same ->hence my "is not changed" restriction, but I'm unsure how to enforce it

Answer (score 2):

The use of a singleton will limit your possibilities, as hoffmale's review points out.  It completely prevents concurrent testing.  However, you'll find that getting the Clock instance to the code that needs it can easily add lots of "tramp data" to intermediated method signatures.  I try to limit that by passing a factory/registry interface that allows classes to access the system interactions they need - time, filesystem, network, etc.  In the tests, populate a mock-factory with the necessary mock objects, and in production, pass a concrete-factory that gives out objects with real system access.

One aspect that's missing is that this interface only gives access to `now()` - it doesn't handle the other clock-related actions that can cause slow tests.  In particular, you'll want sleeps and network- or mutux-related timeouts to respect the mock clock's idea of time.  To achieve that, you'll need to redirect those timeouts to mockable methods.  That's a bigger job, but will give you a much more useful test regime.

I think that when I made something like that (many years ago, and in a different language), I ended up with the `MockTime` storing an ordered list of future events; whenever control entered its code, it could advance the time to match the next event (which could be the end of a sleep, release of a mutex, or an interrupt from an external (mocked) thread, for example).

Answer (score 2):

If you care about performance, you can use templates to provide arguments at compile time.

#### Example

```cpp
template <typename Clock>
class TestClass {
    Clock clock;

    public:
    void testMethod() {
        auto start = clock.currentTime();
        doStuff();
        auto end = clock.currentTime();
    }
}
```

Now you can use any class which has `currentTime` method

**Edit:** The downside of this approach, is if you have a lot of template instantiations, it will cripple your compile times. Do not optimize prematurely. **Profile First!!!**